# In remix how to add accounts in the injected web3 provider?

Tags: remix, metamask, accounts

I got only the first account and I need the other accounts to use them .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an injected web3 tool like metamask once its connected select the Account dropdown below the environment and swap between them

Comment: there is just one account . and i added a 6 accounts in metmask !

Comment: I think you can only use the current selected account from metamask, and if u need a second account then u should selects it first in metamask @DoaaHabeebAlla

Comment: On metamask select the account you want to connect, on the metamask extention right next to your account address it says connected, select it and it will allow you to switch